# Passing an ArrayList from a Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets, jstl

my model returns an arraylist of strings to servlet in the form

```
ArrayList<String> currentCustomer = model.getAllCustomers();
```

i want to pass this arraylist from the servlet to the jsp page. how do i do this? below is what i tried

```
req.setAttribute("currentCustomer", currentCustomer);
```

and in the jsp page, i want to use JSTL to loop over each value and display it. how do i do that? its frustrating me to no end. ive scoured the web but to no avail. any help is greatly appreciated.

here is the jsp code

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<body>
    <div>
        <c:forEach var="customer" items="currentCustomer">
            ${customer}
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you show us your web.xml file? Please include the <web-app> element with all its attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its allrite guys, i solved the problem.. thanks for your help..

apparently the code i was using was outdated (thanks internet!) i was writing this on the header:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

while it should have been

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: and also, the items attribute was incorrect. it shouldnt be <c:forEach var="customer" items="currentCustomer">, it should be <c:forEach var="customer" items="${currentCustomer}">

Answer (score 2):

Let's make it work :)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:forEach var="customer" items="${currentCustomer}">
     <c:out value="${customer.name}" />
     <c:out value="${customer.age}" />
</c:forEach>
```

P.S. jsp:useBean is another way to go...

P.P.S. I also made a correction in the taglib import. That's one of these hard-visible mistakes when you can look on two different entries and think they are the same :)

Comment: yes there are. but even after trying them out, they dont seem to work. neither does this.. do i have to do <jsp:useBean somewhere?

Comment: @Dhruv: you don't need <jsp:useBean>, the currentCustomer attribute in your code example is a String. You would need it if you stored an object of another class than String, e.g. a Customer object.

Comment: @Dhruv: If this code correction from Filip didn't help, you are probably referencing JSTL in a wrong way (probably an incorrect combination of JSTL and Servlet/JSP versions).

Answer (score 0):

It will be smt like

```
<c:forEach var="currentCustomer" items="${customers}">
     ${currentCustomer.name}
     ${currentCustomer.age}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: but how do i return the arraylist to the jsp itself?